# JVM Specification version: 0.9 is too old. (see org.ibex.util.Platform to add support)

Tags: android, sqlite, jdbc

Trying to open a sqlite database from SD Card and getting this weird error message:

This is the code:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Error message:

> JVM Specification version: 0.9 is too old. (see org.ibex.util.Platform
>   to add support)

Comment: JVM in Android?! do you mean DVM? :O

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error because I ported to Android a Java code that used the library sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar.

In fact, I just removed that library from the /libs/ folder, and everything worked well :D

It might be because Android already provides its own library.